# Oracle SQL how do I update a foreign key using a correct and incorrect foreign key derived from a subquery?

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys

I have the following example table:

```
table1
id      values
1       arbitraryvalue
2       arbitraryvalue
3       arbitraryvalue
4       arbitraryvalue
5       arbitraryvalue
6       arbitraryvalue
7       arbitraryvalue
8       arbitraryvalue
9       arbitraryvalue
10      arbitraryvalue
```

Trough the use of a subquery I get the following table:

```
subqueryTable
correctId   incorrectId
2           4
8           6
10          5
```

I have a third table that uses the id as a foreign key.

```
table2
foreignKeyId    otherColumns
2               somedatahere
4               somedatahere
1               somedatahere
5               somedatahere
```

What I want to do is delete the rows with an incorrect id because they are accidental duplicates of the rows with the correct id. 
But in order to do so I need to update the foreign keys with the correct ids.

How can I update the foreign keys?

I'd need something like

```
Update table2
SET foreignKeyId = subqueryTable.correctId
WHERE foreignKeyId = subqueryTable.incorrectId
```

Comment: So what would be your expected data?

Answer (score 1):

You need to update only rows that have invalid identifiers:

```
update table2 t2 set foreignKeyId = (select correctid from subqueryTable 
                                      where t2.ForeignKeyId = incorrectId)
  where foreignKeyId in (select incorrectid from subqueryTable);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use correlated subquery in update:

```
UPDATE table2 t2
SET foreignKeyId = (SELECT s.correctId
           FROM   subqueryTable s
           WHERE  t2.foreignKeyId = s.incorrectId)
;
```